# How can I access my ADFS login page from outside of the corp network in Azure?

Tags: azure, adfs2.0

I have set up 3 VM's on a network in Azure -
1. AD
2. ADFS (federated with O365)
3. DirSync for O365

I was able to successfully federate with O365 via the ADFS in Azure. However, I am unable to access the ADFS login page from outside of the network -- I can only access it from within the VM and login to O365. When I try to hit the ADFS login page from outside of the network, I am redirected to a page not found.

I tried running fiddler to see where the choke was and I see that there is a DNS error -- Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "sameer-adfs1.syxix.com" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known.

I then ran a NSLOOKUP on sameer-adfs1.syxix.com and that returns 104.40.9.111 which is the external IP Address of the server.

Basically, when I go to my O365 login page from outside the network, and sign in as "charles@syxix.com" for example, I'd like it to redirect to my ADFS login page -- this happens when I am on the network, but not from the outside. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your ADFS is exposed over internet? If you get page not found, it means that it's not.

Comment: Figured it out - basically I needed to have HTTPS Port open in my Azure dashboard on manage.windowsazure.com. Previously I only had it open on my Firewall which is why it did not work.